# Python boto function for getting ALL policies associated with a ROLE?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-iam

I am looking to parse ALL IAM policies in my account for IP address restriction information.  This includes groups, users, and roles.

So with [boto.iam](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/iam.html), I can:

- list all my groups
- iterate over those groups, getting all the policies for each group
- iterate over those policies, parsing them for the IP restriction clause.

I can do the same for my users.

However, there is no equivalent "get_all_role_policies" command that I can find.  I have verified that I can attach more than one policy to each role.

Am I missing something, or does boto just not support the same functionality for roles as they do for groups and users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of boto that I have has a `list_role_policies` method and a `get_role_policy` method similar to the ones for users and groups.  Those should allow you to find all policies for all roles.

Comment: Awesome.  I simply changed `connection.get_all_role_policies(role_name) to connection.list_role_policies(role_name) and it worked.  It sucks that the function nomenclature isn't consistent across all three types of policy container types.

Comment: Yes, that is unfortunate.  Glad its working for you now.

Answer (score 0):

You can user the IAM Role resource https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Role.attached_policies

```
iam = boto3.resource('iam')
role = iam.Role('<role_name>')
for p in role.attached_policies.all():
    print(p)
```